# Storing polymorphic types in one data structure

Tags: c++, oop

You have an animal Shelter. Shelter can store variable number of Animals. You put many Animals (Dogs and Cats) into the shelter.

Then you tell the employee to randomly select and bring you few Animals. You don't know what type of an Animal he selected.
You tell them to Speak. Some of them goes "bark", some goes "meow".

Important! Dogs can fetch and Cats can't.
If you know for sure you've selected a Dog it should be able to fetch right away (without upcasting from Animal to Dog for example)

How to implement this kind of logic? (preferably without boost::any)

Here is a partially working example: http://ideone.com/kR4788

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Animal {};

class Shelter {
    private:
        std::map<int, Animal*> animals;
    public:
        void Add(Animal* animal) {
            animals[animals.size()] = animal;
        };
        Animal* Select(int index) {
            return animals[index];
        }
};

class Dog: public Animal {
    public:
        void Speak() { cout << "bark" << endl; }
        void Fetch() {}
};

class Cat: public Animal {
    public:
        void Speak() { cout << "meow" << endl; }
};

Shelter shelter;

int main() {
    shelter.Add(new Cat());
    shelter.Add(new Dog());

    // I'd like to make it work like this
    //
    // shelter.Select(0)->Speak(); /* meow */
    // shelter.Select(1)->Speak(); /* bark */
    //
    // Like below but without upcasting to given animal

    ((Cat*) shelter.Select(0))->Speak();
    ((Dog*) shelter.Select(1))->Speak();

    // I know under index 1 is a Dog so it can fetch!
    //
    // shelter.Select(1)->Fetch(); /* no segfault */
    //
    // Like below but without upcasting to given animal
    ((Dog*) shelter.Select(1))->Fetch();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Comment: `Speak` should be pure virtual in the `Animal` class ...

Comment: Look at this: http://ideone.com/YgsIzu for an example of how you can use virtual functions.

Comment: @jpw Could you paste that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request I post my comment as an answer. The full source is in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YgsIzu):

In class Animal:

```
class Animal {
  public:
    virtual void Speak() const = 0;
    virtual void Fetch() const { cout << "This animal can't fetch" << endl;};

    virtual ~Animal(){ }
};
```

The virtual destructor is needed to ensure that the correct destructor is called for objects that derive from the base class. Without the virtual destructor only the base class destructor would be called and not the destructor for the derived object.

In Dog:

```
void Fetch() const { cout << "fetch" << endl; }
```

And in main:

```
shelter.Select(0)->Speak();
shelter.Select(1)->Speak();

shelter.Select(0)->Fetch();
shelter.Select(1)->Fetch();
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep polymorphism and be able to alter object properties at the same time? Using `const` keywords makes object read-only, do you have any idea how to achieve both?

Comment: @user291196 `const`isn't related to polymorphism so if you need to modify the object through a method simply don't use const for that method.

Comment: @user291196 Add `=0`to the Speak function in animal to make it a pure virtual function; It should look like this: `virtual void Speak()=0;`

Comment: Yes I noticed that! Thanks! Now I have to seriously read about virtual functions, thanks again!

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/

Comment: BTW: `~Animal()` should be `virtual`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed, I just added what was needed to implement basic polymorphism and didn't make any other changes to the code.

Comment: @Jarod42 Even if all subclasses doesn't have a destructor specified?

Comment: @jpw: You didn't add the virtual destructor which is important in polymorphism, (you didn't fix memory-leak nether) but you added the `const`...

Comment: @user291196: yes, by the way you should delete the memory you allocated. I suggest to transform `std::map<int, Animal*> animals;` into `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals;`

Comment: @Jarod42 I updated my answer and changed the code on Ideone. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @jpw: You miss the memleaks. But it is not related to OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You can try to use a `dynamic_cast` to cast your `Animal` object into a `Dog` and then call the `fetch` method:

```
Dog *foo = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(shelter.Select(1));
if (foo) {
  foo->Fetch();
}
```

If the `dynamic_cast` fails, it will return `null` so make sure to check if the object is not `null` before using it. For more information on `dynamic_cast`, check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast).

---

You can add a [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) function to your `Animal` interface:

```
class Animal {
  public:
    virtual void speak();
};
```

Also, on an unrelated note, your `speak` method doesn't seem to be modifying the object so you should consider putting them as `const`:

```
class Animal {
  public:
    virtual void speak() const;
};
```

You can find more information on const-correctness [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness).

Comment: The question was about `fetch`, which is not in `Animal`

Comment: But yes, `speak` should be `virtual`.

Comment: An animal could provide an empty default implementation of fetch, if that's a suitable interpretation of "do nothing".

Comment: @Aliou I didn't know you can declare methods as const and honestly I don't know why it matters but I will read on that. What should I do if I want to modify the object from within a method? When I simply remove the `const` keywords it won't compile.

Comment: You forgot to remove the `const` from the method `speak` in the `Cat` class. You need to have the same method signature on all the inherited classes of `Animal`. Since `Animal` doesn't have the `const` keyword, you need to remove it from the inherited classes.

Comment: @Aliou yes, I've noticed that a second before you sent your comment but it seems nothing changed even though I removed it. The link above is still valid.

Comment: @user291196 Substituting the `Animal` class with the one above in the accepted answer, I get this: http://ideone.com/ODk6wy

Comment: But as @piokuc said without `virtual` there will be no polymorphism

Comment: Yes, I've accepted that answer since it does what I've asked for but renders objects to be read-only since methods are declared as `const`. If I could have both I'd be thrilled

Comment: @user291196 then remove the `const` keyword. It was just a suggestion because I thought you didn't modify the object. But since you increment the variable `i`, the method can not be const.

Comment: @Aliou I did, what I'm trying to say is there are still errors http://ideone.com/QCwFG6

Comment: @user291196 You forgot the `= 0` after your virtual method: http://ideone.com/Oo1qb1

Comment: @Aliou Yes I noticed that! Thanks! Now I have to seriously read about virtual functions, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As `Aliou` noticed `speak` should be declared `virtual` in `Animal`, otherwise the hierarchy is rather useless, or, in other words, there is no polymorphism.

Testing if an `Animal` is a `Dog` (and upcasting at the same time) with `dynamic_cast<Dog*>` is an option to consider. Not pretty, but it works.

```
Dog *dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*> shelter.Select(1);
if (dog) dog->Fetch();
```

(`dynamic_cast` to a pointer never throws, as others suggested...)

Another solution is to define `virtual` `Fetch` in `Animal`, perhaps as a NOP (`{}`), so you don't have to define it in animals which don't fetch.

Comment: Casting is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask the employee to return only animals which could fetch, therefore you must check (cast) each animal can fetch.

The alternative is to add a dummy fetch function to animal, which doesn't do anything except for dogs.